# Import Errors on Imutils

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to import Imutils for my Raspberry Pi project, and after moving the files of Imutils from my python 3.7 directory to my python 2.7 directory, I'm still having issues.

I got this error when trying to run my script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_script_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 292
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xef' in file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py on line 293, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I think this has to do with python not having the proper encoding info.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> moving the files of Imutils from my python 3.7 directory to my python 2.7 directory

This sounds... questionable. Modules are often written with a specific major version in mind because of various incompatibilities - in this case, the default source code encoding.

My first suggestion would be to try to install a Python 2.7 version of the `imutils` module, if it exists. If not, and if you're comfortable changing the source code, you can try to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of the problematic file, which tells Python 2.7 which encoding to use.

Also, in case it's helpful, here's a similar question: [Running Python 2.7 Code With Unicode Characters in Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265146/running-python-2-7-code-with-unicode-characters-in-source)

Comment: I didn't think about that, but it didn't recognize it either on my 3.7 directory